# Unable to open a realm at path xxx

Tags: android, realm

I'm using the `Realm database` in our new project,however I got an `Exception` when open `Realm`,the full exception message is like this:

> io.realm.exceptions.RealmFileException: Unable to open a realm at path '/data/data/com.xxx/files/xxx.c8c50ce7d6dd4c85ace822d1d1d56dc0.realm': Not a Realm file. in /Users/cm/Realm/realm-java/realm/realm-library/src/main/cpp/io_realm_internal_SharedRealm.cpp line 92 Kind: ACCESS_ERROR.
>       at io.realm.internal.SharedRealm.nativeGetSharedRealm(Native Method)
>       at io.realm.internal.SharedRealm.getInstance(SourceFile:205)
>       at io.realm.internal.SharedRealm.getInstance(SourceFile:182)
>       at io.realm.RealmCache.createRealmOrGetFromCache(SourceFile:124)
>       at io.realm.Realm.getInstance(SourceFile:227)

This `exception` is hard to reproduce.
What can be done to solve this problem ?

Comment: Depends on what your `file()` and `directory()` parameters are on the `RealmConfiguration.Builder`

Comment: I wonder if `c8c50ce7d6dd4c85ace822d1d1d56dc0` is too long.

Comment: What version of Realm are you using? Can you reproduce it yourself or is this from a crash reporting tool?

Comment: Did you find the solution?